# Drop a trigger from within the trigger body

Tags: mysql

I want to run a trigger once and only once the first time a condition is satisfied.

To do this I would like to drop the trigger from within the body of the trigger itself. I have two questions: 1) is there a better way than this and 2) will anything weird happen if I drop the trigger inside the trigger body?

This is what I have so far. For context: There's another process running moving things to done and in a particular case it does not write the result so in that case I want to run a script such that when they're all done I want this trigger to read some values another table and then remove the trigger itself so that it doesn't run every single time stuff gets done normally.

```
CREATE TRIGGER some_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
  SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE status!='done') = 0)
  THEN BEGIN 
    UPDATE table_name SET result = (SELECT other.result FROM table_name, other WHERE other.id = table_name.id);
    DROP TRIGGER some_trigger;
  END;
  ELSE BEGIN END;
  END CASE;
```

EDIT: also a third question, what does "FOR EACH ROW" mean? I only want the trigger to run once, not once per row. Looking at the docs it seems like "FOR EACH ROW" is not optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DROP TRIGGER cannot be performed within a Trigger.

To explain why, firstly, DROP TRIGGER causes an implicit commit, and secondly, commits cannot occur within triggers. Details below:

1. DROP TRIGGER causes an implicit commit

See (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html):

> The statements listed in this section (and any synonyms for them) implicitly end any transaction active in the current session, as if you had done a COMMIT before executing the statement.
>
> ...
>
> Data definition language (DDL) statements that define or modify database objects. ALTER EVENT, ALTER FUNCTION, ALTER PROCEDURE, ALTER SERVER, ALTER TABLE, ALTER VIEW, CREATE DATABASE, CREATE EVENT, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE INDEX, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE ROLE, CREATE SERVER, CREATE SPATIAL REFERENCE SYSTEM, CREATE TABLE, CREATE TRIGGER, CREATE VIEW, DROP DATABASE, DROP EVENT, DROP FUNCTION, DROP INDEX, DROP PROCEDURE, DROP ROLE, DROP SERVER, DROP SPATIAL REFERENCE SYSTEM, DROP TABLE, **DROP TRIGGER**, DROP VIEW, INSTALL PLUGIN, RENAME TABLE, TRUNCATE TABLE, UNINSTALL PLUGIN.

2. Commits cannot occur within a trigger:

See (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> The trigger cannot use statements that explicitly or implicitly begin or end a transaction, such as START TRANSACTION, **COMMIT**, or ROLLBACK. (ROLLBACK to SAVEPOINT is permitted because it does not end a transaction.).